# Get ScrollViewer.ViewPortHeight in XAML

Tags: wpf, binding, scrollviewer

All,

I'm sure this is easy to do, but I'm still trying to do this.  I can get the ViewPortHeight of a scrollviewer in code-behind and plug into loaded and size-changed events to manage objects related to ViewPortHeight, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this without going to CodeBehind at all.

i.e. what I would like to do is somehow get ViewPortHeight (and ViewPortWidth) in XAML and Bind them either directly to another element's size property or to my ViewModel (with my own IValueconverter, of course).  This way, I hope to more easily manage related controls whenever a window is resized (or whenever a scaletransform is done).

i.e. in PseudoCode, this is what I hope to accomplish (without CodeBehind)

(assuminging MyConverter is an IValueConverter in resources)

```
<ScrollViewer Name="MyScrollViewer">
    <loc:MyControl Width="{Binding Path=ViewPortWidth, ElementName=MyScrollViewer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=10}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"to manage objects related to ViewportWidth" - that sounds to me like you need a layout container such as Grid which allows you to create rows and columns. Inside those you can place whatever UIElement you wish. You can also tell a cell to have fix size or to use relative values based on avialable space.

If you want to figure out ViewportWidth you will need to do this:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="MyScrollViewer">
    <StackPanel>
     <Button Width="100"/>
     <Button Width="200"/>
     <Button Width="300"/>
     <Button Width="400"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
<TextBlock Text={Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer, Path=ViewportWidth}"/>
```

ScollViewer has the property called ViewportWidth. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx

Comment: The problem is that ViewPortWidth (at least as far as I can tell) is that when the ViewPortWidth changes during runtime, I don't see any updates to properties that I bind to ViewPortWidth

Comment: According to MSDN: ViewportWidth = Gets a value that contains the horizontal size of the content's viewport. Isnt that what you wish to find out?

Comment: Also, I should note that the Width is auto, which is why I need to retrieve ViewPortWidth and listen for whenever this changes (preferably without codebehind, but I already have a solution that uses CodeBehind and bypasses the valueconverter).

Comment: Snowy, the problem is that if you try something similar to my code (which also uses Binds to ViewPortWidth) it doesn't update.  I actually get a BindingExpressionError ('ViewPortWidth' property not found on 'object' ''ScrollViewer').  Nonetheless, I'll double-check that I'm binding to the right ElementName.

Comment: Let me tell you something about the scrollviewer. It doesnt really cares what content it has. It just cares what avialable size it has to be able to display itself. If you have a window with 300x300 and you place the scrollviewer in it. The available size will be 300x300 and that size will scrollviewer use to display itself. Its next step is to tell its content which is in my case a StackPanel to take as much space as it needs. It doesnt tell StackPanel to use 300x300. It tells to StackPanel to have all the freedom. If StackPanel wants 600x800 the scrollviewer will display scrollbars.

Comment: You get the error message because its not "ViewPortWidth" its "ViewportWidth" you misspelled it wrong my friend.

Comment: Okay.  I think I just found my problem.  It's ViewportWidth, not ViewPortWidth.

Comment: One more time for you. You cant set ScrollViewer.Width to auto because it only allows numbers. You can set auto to columns width of a Grid which is a layout container.

Comment: I wasn't trying to get ScrollViewer.Width, so that is not a problem.  I was trying to get ScrollViewier.ViewportWidth.  I resolved my issue, though (I had ViewPortWidth, instead, which was causing my binding to fail).

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="MyScrollViewer">
    <loc:MyControl Width="{Binding Path=ViewportWidth, ElementName=MyScrollViewer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=10}" />
<!--Notice that it is ViewportWith, not ViewPortWidth-->
</ScrollViewer>
```